# A recursive interface for a React Typescript component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, interface, recursive-datastructures

The component is a breadcrumb, it must receive as props an object that contains a title and an url and also an option children node. The maximum depth should be 5, in this case this is a props example:

```
myProps = {
            title: "level 1",
            url: "/",
            children: {
                        title: "level 2"
                        url: "/level2"
                        children: { 
                                    title: "level 3"
                                    url: "level2/level3"
                                    children: {
                                                title: "level 4"
                                                url: "level2/level3/level4"
                                                children: {
                                                            title: "level 5"
                                                            url: "/level2/level3/level4/level5"
                                                          }
                                               }
                                  }
                       }
          };
```

But it can also have less nesting, for example:

```
myProps = {
            title: "title1"
            url: "/"
            children: null
          }
```

How should the interface look like?

Is this correct?

```
export interface MyProps {
  title: string;
  url: string;
  children: MyProps;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to account for those without children, so

```js
export interface MyProps {
  title: string;
  url: string;
  children?: MyProps | null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your interface is a good start! If I get it right, `MyProps.children` is optional, right? In that case you can declare it like that:

```
export interface MyProps {
  title: string;
  url: string;
  children?: MyProps;
}
```

This allows you to leave out the property `children` during declaration of a variable of type `MyProps` and to explicitly assign it `undefined`:

```
const myProps: MyProps = {
  title: "title1",
  url: "/"
};

const otherProps: MyProps = {
  title: "title1",
  url: "/",
  children: {
    title: "title2",
    url: "/otherUrl"
  }
};

const yetOtherProps: MyProps = {
  title: "title1",
  url: "/",
  children: undefined
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know upfront the number of nested properties you can use this utility type:

```js
export interface MyProps {
  title: string;
  url: string;
  children: undefined;
}

type Recursive<
  Length extends number,
  Counter extends number[] = [],
  Result = MyProps
  > =
  (Length extends Counter['length']
    ? Result
    : {
      [Prop in keyof MyProps]:
      (Prop extends 'children'
        ? (Length extends [...Counter, 1]['length']
          ? Recursive<Length, [...Counter, 1], undefined>
          : undefined | Recursive<Length, [...Counter, 1], Result>)
        : (Prop extends 'title'
          ? `${string} ${[...Counter, 1]['length'] extends string | number ? [...Counter, 1]['length'] : ''}`
          : MyProps[Prop])
      )
    })

const test0: Recursive<5> = { // ok
  title: `a 1`,
  url: 'string',
  children: {
    title: `a 2`,
    url: ' string',
    children: {
      title: `  3`,
      url: 'string',
      children: {
        title: ` 4`,
        url: 'string',
        children: {
          title: ` 5`,
          url: 'string',
          children: undefined
        }
      },
    },
  },
}

const test1: Recursive<6> = { // ok
  title: `a 1`,
  url: 'string',
  children: {
    title: `a 2`,
    url: ' string',
    children: {
      title: `  3`,
      url: 'string',
      children: {
        title: ` 4`,
        url: 'string',
        children: {
          title: ` 5`,
          url: 'string',
          children: {
            title: ` 6`,
            url: 'string',
            children: undefined
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
}

const test2: Recursive<5> = {
  title: `a 1`,
  url: 'string',
  children: {
    title: `a 2`,
    url: ' string',
    children: {
      title: `  3`,
      url: 'string',
      children: {
        title: ` 4`,
        url: 'string',
        children: {
          title: ` 5`,
          url: 'string',
          children: {
            title: ` 6`,
            url: 'string',
            children: undefined
          }
        },
      },
    },
  },
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgWQE8AFKCMAZzgG8AoOOGBGAG2AC44KYpkBzANz04AVygtO3XkkHDsACwQsAJlGBJOIpMuDpkwZUIC+tU7RiEweAErBsYiggBuwADzCAMur4x5cUKjaVEgiALYARmgANMIAwhBaqFD+IIHKwWGRUADaALpwALxweTEMthQiLPBFRKTkFMIAfIXCABReMr4paVTxiWjZAORsnfKDucIMAPxw5ZUwk3CcdAyrxXVgiEhwANbAhBDoBCRklLnsiwytG93q6XCDCkqq6oOXqzPt3l0Bd1TZADogX0UNE4ABGXJDEY+MYTNYIuAzWz2KCOFyuDqwqLFIEAkFJHGQnFaHR6JAGRrvNaabS6fTKOAAH1mdgczjcWN8OMBwISoKgRNyOLmVUaAEpqUs4NdTrcgg8mKxgG9EWsZgADAAk1Ck-CMcB1vPx-MJEKhw2+cPl9z1MmZcBCETQSNxfP6gvN0Kt42lg0GRg1UoYnFqpwo2Q2uUliJjqyMkto2AgSG4jGA3AADJwUeyMQBWZpFahwAD0pbgEB2wiVbE4GswEI1pVE4k4gztfEGLaeKjUGhoi1rHDgDbgACZm4sxBIHlwePxu4tey8BysEcP6wwAMxTxEz9udpeIlf95ZSzejuAAFj3aoPDyPLZPij76nPatWl41cHzd8-D4dguMjHp+cCnu+oh0uSBhSiYiJGM+cCIcIKEmEmKZpqg3DgjmbJohyrgAGxFjQZYVlWNbMHWo6NuCd6AU+civquH5ftRI5jpOSGAfO0hdkhEFru8347v+qyMcBAnvEJbGIqJt5IWskn8aBL7PGeg5gYwHFbn+SkIipi4GWssladpOnKluRHiQBbaPlJalgWZpL0hSyjBshJlee8KFrH5PnocmqbwNhMDjnhqLom4haFOZ350Qx9lAapPYsZp64MAlE7ibxTGmelkGZexVlXnAu4GUZIEGWZxVrAptkScl+VqrVnmifpnlVdJ2ltRZlk0T+NnecpzWOSNqwudBDKefBaoBf5SEBWhtBAA)

**Explanation**

`Recursive parameters`:
`Length` - the number of nested properties
`Counter` - since it is impossible to make math operations in TS I'm using a tuple and increase the length every time by 1 `[...Counter, 1]`
`Result` - straightforward - result :D

**How does it work?**

Each step starts with comparison of `Length` and `Counter['length']`. If `Counter['length']` is equal desired number of nested properties - return `Result`.

Otherwise, iterate through each property of `MyProps` end each time when loop encounter `children` property - call it recursively with increased `Counter`.

**`Recursive<5>`** - means that you are allowed to declare up to 5 nested children. You can declare less but no more

I have added an extra logic for `title` property. Each `title` property has its own number.

That's all.

P.S. [Here](https://catchts.com/recursive-ds), in my blog, you can find more explanation